# Are Simultaneous cURL HTTP requests the answer?

Tags: php, curl

first let me start with the obligatory "Im somewhat of a noob, stupid question etc". I have something I would like to accomplish and need a little help researching the right solution. I have several web forms that are transmitted cross domain through a cURL processor (the real form processor has to reside on a separate domain due to CRM issues) so I can use jQuery's AJAX function to display the appropriate message based on the response.

That's easy enough. We have now switched our ESP and would like to only send the email address and name to it to store in our marketing database. So included in one form is a lot of information but we only need to send those two items to our ESP.

Should this be done with the cURL script that sends the info to our cross domain form processor or to the processor itself? If I am unclear in any of this let me know and I will expand. I know it's not ideal to "siphon" in formation to two destinations, but that decision was made above my head. Below is an example of one of my current cURL scripts.

```
<?php

$url = 'myremoteserver.com';
$referred_by_text = $_POST["referred_by_text"];
$broker_text = $_POST["broker_text"];
$email1 = $_POST["email1"];
$radiobutton = $_POST["radiobutton"];
$trade_futures = $_POST["trade_futures"];
$trade_fx = $_POST["trade_fx"];
$trade_equities = $_POST["trade_equities"];

$fields = array(
'referred_by_text'=>urlencode($referred_by_text),
'broker_text'=>urlencode($broker_text),
'email1'=>urlencode($email1),
'radiobutton'=>urlencode($radiobutton),
'trade_futures'=>urlencode($trade_futures),
'trade_fx'=>urlencode($trade_fx),
'trade_equities'=>urlencode($trade_equities)
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the marketing database is on a 3rd distinct domain, separate from the original web host and the 2nd CRM domain? And all 3 domains are hosted on separate servers?

You could do it in 1 cURL request if on the CRM server script, after processing the POST vars you do a header redirect that attachs the POST vars as GET vars to the ESP server url. But that's probably not a good idea. And w/ cURL you cant do 2 "simultaneous" requests, you can only do one after the other.

If it were me, I'd write a chronjob on the ESP server to grab all new/modified records from the CRM database for that day, but maybe that won't work in your situation.

also a suggestion, if your form field names will always match submitted var names, you can replace:

```
$referred_by_text = $_POST["referred_by_text"];
$broker_text = $_POST["broker_text"];
$email1 = $_POST["email1"];
$radiobutton = $_POST["radiobutton"];
$trade_futures = $_POST["trade_futures"];
$trade_fx = $_POST["trade_fx"];
$trade_equities = $_POST["trade_equities"];

$fields = array(
'referred_by_text'=>urlencode($referred_by_text),
'broker_text'=>urlencode($broker_text),
'email1'=>urlencode($email1),
'radiobutton'=>urlencode($radiobutton),
'trade_futures'=>urlencode($trade_futures),
'trade_fx'=>urlencode($trade_fx),
'trade_equities'=>urlencode($trade_equities)
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');
```

with something like this:

```
$allowed_vars = array("referred_by_text","broker_text","email1","radiobutton","trade_futures","trade_fx","trade_equities");
$outputarray = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($key,$allowed_vars)){
        $outputarray[] = $key.'='.urlencode($value);
    }
}
$fields_string = implode('&',$outputarray);
```

this will make it a lot easier to add or modify field names since you only change the instance in the allowed array and not in multiple places. the in_array protects you from extra unwanted POST values, and the implode will join your name/value pairs without the need to remove the last &

Comment: What about curl_mulit family of functions?

Comment: Or simply having a second hidden form with a hidden input whos value echos the email in the first form. Using a second action to send that form to the ESP?

Comment: I don't think the double form method will work, since when you submit it should redirect to the action target of the first form, losing the information and target of form 2. Also if I remember correctly when you submit a form, it only submits THAT form not all forms on the page. And I haven't seen curl_multi before, that might work but I'm not sure what the advantage is to doing it that way.